# Laravel 3 search function controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am still new in Laravel. I'm trying to create search box for searching users by their username.

What is the best way to create controller for Laravel search box?

The view that I have look as follows:

```
{{ Form::search_open('/users/search') }}
    {{ Form::search_box('search','admin', array('class' => 'input-medium')) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Search'); }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

I have the controller as below:

```
class Users_Controller extends Base_Controller {
    public function action_search() {
        $userdetail = Input::get("username");
        $details = User::where('username', '=', Input::get('username')) - > first();
        return Redirect::to_route("users");
    }
}
```

Comment: Before going answering your question, I would definitely encourage you to use Laravel 4 instead.

Comment: Also what have you tried? I mean, did you create the view, the controller or the routes? Can you provide that info so we can help you more?

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo This is the view:

{{ Form::search_open('/users/search') }}       
{{ Form::search_box('search','admin', array('class' => 'input-medium')) }}
        {{ Form::submit('Search'); }}
        {{ Form::close() }}
<br/>

Comment: I'm including this to your question, do you have something else?

Comment: The `{{ Form::search_open(...) }}` should be `{{ Form::open(...) }}`.

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo I try to put the controllers in users.php controller .
public function action_search()
        {
                $userdetail = Input::get("username");
                $details = User::where('username', '=', Input::get('username'))->first();
                return Redirect::to_route("users");
        }


Model:

class User extends Eloquent
{
        //because the user didnt use plural naming
        public static $table = 'user';
....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You may try something like this :

**Route :**

```
Route::get('/search', array('as' => 'user.search', 'uses' => 'user@search'));
```

**View :** (search/index.blade.php)

```
{{ Form::open(URL::to_route('user.search')) }}
{{ $errors->has('username') ? $errors->first('username','<span class="error">:message</span>') : '' }}
{{ Form::text('username', Input::old('username', $username), array('class' => 'input-medium')) }}
{{ Form::submit('Search'); }}
{{ Form::close() }}

@if ( isset($user) )
    @foreach ($user->results as $user)
        {{ $user->first_name }}
        {{ $user->last_name }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

**Controller :** (controllers/user.php)

```
class User_Controller extends Base_Controller
{
    public function action_search()
    {
        $data['username'] = Input::get('username');
        if(Input::get())
        {
            $rules=array( 'username' => 'required' );
            $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
            if($validation->fails())
            {
                return Redirect::back()->with_errors($validation)->with_input();
            }
            else {
                data['user'] = User::where('username', '=', Input::get('username'));
            }
        }
        return View::make('search.index', $data);
    }
}
```

**Model :** (models/user.php)

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    // ...
}
```